# Некорректно работает код на С в Code::Blocks

Tags: c, математика, float

Выполнял лабораторную работу по программированию и столкнулся с проблемой выдачи неправильного результата. Ошибку найти не могу.
Основное задание: при вводе `x`, `y`, `z` нужно вычислить `a` и `b`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С `b` проблем нет. В `а` результат не совпадает с требуемым. Проверял на symbolab.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

    main()
{
    float x, y, z, a=0, b=0;
    printf("Input x y z"); scanf("%f%f%f", &x, &y, &z);
    if (x<1)
        printf("invalid value x ");
    if (y<0)
        printf("invalid value y ");
    if (z<=0)
        printf("invalid value z ");
    if (z==1)
        printf("invalid value z ");
    a= (sqrt(x-1) - pow(y,(1/3))) / (1 + (pow(x,2) / 2) + (pow(x,4) / 4)); printf("a=%f",a);
    b= x*(atan(z)+pow(z,-(x+3))); printf("b=%f",b);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражение `1/3` означает **целочисленное** деление, и результат равен 0.
Делите как `1.0/3`, например...

Вообще говоря, для таких простых степеней, как 2 и 4, прибегать к мощи `pow` нет смысла. Я бы считал так:

```
double t = x*x/2;
a = (sqrt(x-1)-pow(y,1./3))/((t+1)*t+1);
```